GPU not showing after installing CPU
My GPU is not recognized whenever I install my i3 10100 CPU.
The CPU was installed on my z490-p board but it eventually started having issues with the card and the screen output started going blank. I initially thought it was a bad graphics card (GTX 1060 6GB). However, when I placed it in my H410m board running a Celeron, it ran no problems. I thought the card was fine, so I placed back in my z490p to see what would happen, and I got no signal.
Now I thought it was faulty MoBo so I started using H410m board instead that had the Celeron on it, but it was just a bit too slow. I moved the i3 10100 CPU on this board, and guess what? GPU has no signal again.
So it's not a bad graphics card because it's definitely working.
It's not a bad board since the Graphics card works on both boards when the Celeron CPU is in.
Does this mean I have a bad CPU that doesn't communicated with my PCIe Slots anymore?
Is it possible to have a CPU Go bad?

Still a lot of unknowns you haven't described in your troubleshooting. Have you placed the GPU in another slot? How do you know your power supply is sufficient for the i3 CPU and GPU? Have you tried another GPU if you have one?

Possibly bad PCIe controller on the CPU? It is very unlikely, but not impossible. Try another PCIe port if possible.
Also be aware it is possible to disable dedicated graphics in BIOS, check that as well.

Sounds like the CPU might have bent pins. There are definitely pins responsible for PCIe functions on the CPU. Your motherboard chipset has limited direct PCIe lanes.

Thanks for all the responses, So i have placed the GPU in the other slots and it doesn't work there either. It's a 450w Power supply, so it's sufficient enough. I've also tried my other card (GTX 1650s) And it also doesn't show up on the board but works fine if i install the celeron chip.
Is it possible to have bent pins on an intel chip? I didn't pull it out when it started having issues. I pulled it out because it starting giving me problems randomly.

So the the computer came back again....I'm not sure what would have caused it, if reseating the GPU and CPU a few hundred times or setting the BIOS PCIE to GEN 3, but It died again today. but at least it was working for a few couple days. I assume something else is wrong with it now, It still boots off of iGPU, but the gpu is not picking up once again, I also noticed that the main PCIE slot doesn't work, so i use the secondary PCIe slot
